# What does this sentence mean? "If she were a country, she would be in the top 20."

Tags: meaning

According to the article [Asian Games 2018: After CWG Heroics, Paddler Manika Batra Eyes Good Show at Asiad](https://www.news18.com/news/sports/asian-games-2018-after-cwg-heroics-paddler-manika-batra-eyes-good-show-at-asiad-1856853.html):

> What Manika Batra managed to achieve in the Commonwealth Games for Indian table tennis was something unprecedented. She left Gold Coast with four medals overall – the most by an Indian athlete at the games. **If she were a country, she would be in the top 20.**

This sentence really got me confused.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like the sentence has its *literal* meaning: she won as many medals as some *countries* won, which ended up in the top 20 (of 71 participating countries) at the games.

Comment: Yes, the formulation is functionally the same as the one here: "If California were an independent country instead of a state, its economy would rank in the top 10 in the world." It's simply a lively way to indicate that the number at the core of the sentence is an impressive one